# What are the possible reasons, the consumer leaves the consumer group?

Tags: spring-kafka

I am struggling to find out the issue, for what the reason the consumer is getting stopped.

The issue is the consumer is getting stopped after a certain time ( around 4:52 sec) But be a able to consume the messages and able to process.

As per my understanding the reason for the consumer to stop is, the consumer will not be able to commit the offset (processing time is more than max.poll.interval.ms) within max.poll.interval.ms.

are there any other reasons ?

Here are my basic consumer properties :

```
max.poll.records = 2
auto.offset.reset = latest
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
idle.poll.interval = 60000 (between two polls)
no.of.consumers =1
consumer.group.id = test2
listener.auto.start = true
```

I see some statements in log -
Received user wakeup,
Raising WakeupException in response to user wakeup,
Executing onLeavePrepare with generation Generation

Can someone help on this ?

Note : We are a consumer to the event hub, and on this connectivity we are seeing this issue.But when we connect to the Kafka we do not see any issues.

@Gary , Can you please help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the kafka configuration side, everything looks fine. The issue we found is at the docker pods, where the health of the pod is not being sent. Because livenessProbe - port is different than the application configuration port (By mistake i have hard coded a different port) . Any way thanks for this forum !!!!

Comment: Made a similar mistake. Thanks for putting the answer.